# perl printing out results of a select statement

Tags: perl, dbi

I'm new at perl. What is the best way to print out the results of a select statement (DBI). I want to be able to print it out to a file (and format it nicely) and also be able to store it in a variable (with formatting (\n... and stuff)) because I want to be able to email the results so I will either attach the file or use the body. I already have a email module i want to use (MIME::Lite::TT::HTML).
Thanks!!

Comment: Where/what did you search ? What have you try ? http://search.cpan.org is a good start... http://google.com too

Comment: Check out http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html

Comment: @sputnick I didn't find anything that does what I want(at either locations) so I asked here. The only thing I know how to do is loop through the results but there has to be a module or something that does it better.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what output you want. "\n and stuff" is pretty basic and covers pretty much any output format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you know how to loop through stuff, then you can `$sth->execute` your query, loop through the results and `print` them wherever and however you want.

You can use [`sprintf()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) to format the result, or, as you mentioned, use [`Template::Toolkit`](http://search.cpan.org/~abw/Template-Toolkit-2.24/lib/Template/Toolkit.pod)

I know this might not be very helpful for you, but if you don't show us your SQL query, some sample formatting and some start-up code that you've tried, there is no way we can further help you.

Also, reading some perl tutorials would be of great help for you if you want to get the jobs done fast. There are many [**very good free perl tutorials available**](http://perl-tutorial.org/) on the internet